# Keras Conv1D on Multiple Time Series : One at a time

Tags: keras

I have a numpy array that is shaped as (number of observations, number of time steps, number of features). This equates to say 59 features (i.e. time series) each of length 24 (number of time steps above). This is the standard setup for input into an RNN.

What I would like to do is feed this into a model where the first step is a 1D convolution on each series separately and then concatenate the 59 outputs into the next layer (dense layer or an LSTM and then dense layer).

If I loop through the number of features and apply a convolution to each series, how should the input X be structured?

For example, say my data is as follows:

```
var=np.array([[[1., 3., 5., 7.],
        [2., 4., 6., 8.]],

       [[9., 11., 13., 15.],
        [10., 12., 14., 16.]],

       [[17., 19., 21., 23.],
        [18., 20., 22., 24.]]])
```

where the first observation, time series 1 is [1,2] and the second time series is [3,4]....and the first observations fourth time series is [7,8].

```
nb_filters=(8,4)
filter_length=(5,5)
dense=(16,8)


    conv_layers=[]
    input=Input(shape=(None,no_timesteps,no_features))

    for i in range(no_features):
        series=Lambda(lambda x: x[:, i])(input)
        print(series.shape)
        conv_layer=Conv1D(nb_filters[0], kernel_size=filter_length[0], padding='valid',activation='relu')(series)
        conv_layer = MaxPooling1D()(conv_layer)
        conv_layer=Conv1D(nb_filters[1], kernel_size=filter_length[1], padding='valid',activation='relu')(conv_layer)
        conv_layer = MaxPooling1D()(conv_layer)
        conv_layers.append(conv_layer)
    merge_layer=Concatenate(axis=1)(conv_layers)
    merge_layer= Flatten()(merge_layer)
    output=Dense(dense[0], activation='sigmoid')(merge_layer)

    nn=Model(inputs=inputs,outputs=output)
    nn.compile(optimizer=RMSprop(), loss='binary_crossentropy')
    nn.summary()
    nn.fit(X,y, epochs=5)
```

First, this doesn't work as expected since the print statement gives a shape of (?, 24, 59) which doesnt appear that I am actually slicing in the lambda. I expected each slice to be a specific time series of shape (1,24) where 24 is the length of each series. The idea is to have the 1D convolution ran over this single time series (repeat for all 59 series) and concatenate them together.

Answer (score 0):

The input shape must contain the time steps and num_features only.
therefore instead of:

```
input=Input(shape=(None, no_timesteps,no_features))
```

try:

```
input=Input(shape=(no_timesteps,no_features))
```

Answer (score -1):

You must use:

`input=Input(shape=(None, no_timesteps,no_features))`

or

`input=Input(shape=(number_of_samples, no_timesteps,no_features))`

The input layer is a tensor which must have the same shape as your training data.

Comment: Even after adding that, there are still issues. I updated the question to better reflect.

Comment: I think I have the same issue in this post: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/71545/keras-loaded-model-output-is-different-from-the-training-model-output

Could you fix it?